# database modelling challenges

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to model a student database but I am unsure of how to represent the student, assessment taken, and student results. Below is the description of the scenario:

Several students are offering one or more subjects, these subjects have one or more assessments. How would the you represent  students, the subject offered, the assessment taken and the results of the assessment taken by the students? I have attached a copy of the design I made so far.

- my intension is to design a database where querying of the student,subject,assessment,
  and assessment result can be possible and easy.

[Full-size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm6Aa.png)

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: which application are you using to design the ER model?

Comment: Salem With my approach querying the data you want is quite simple, once you just need the id of the subject and the id of the student to obtain all the assessments he had.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should have a ternary relationship between student, subject and assessment owning the assessment result. This is necessary in the case where a student can have many subject for the same assessment.

Otherwise if an assessment have many subject but only one for a given student you have different choice :

You can keep the ternary.

You can otherwise store the subject id and result in a student - assessment relationship table

or the student id and result in a subject - assessment table.

This should depend on the way you will usually query those tables (all subject for assessment A, all students with subject X for assessment A, all results for subject X for assessment A, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This have several ways to resolve, but why you don't use the Students*---*Subject relationship to associate the assessment to. Because assessment is directly related with this association. So it can't make sense without the relation between a student and a Subject.

You can call the derived table from the has_and_belongs to many relationship between Students and Subject, Assessment with the following fields(There is no place that obey you to call this association student_subjects):

ASSESSMENT

id:PK

student_id:FK

subject_id:FK

assessment_result

created_at, TIMESTAMP

Imagine that the student can make several assessments during their school year, you can save phase 1, phase 2, or Exam1, Exam2, etc... in other field in this table.

The timestamp will provide you a way to know the last result that a student had for a subject.

This is just my point of view, correct me if there is something that i'm not seeing.